How to accelerate calculation of a nested integral
Setup
Let $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ be positive functions defined on $t \in [t_1, t_2]$. They are sampled uniformly within this interval, with a timestep of $\Delta t$.
Question
I want to calculate the following integral numerically
$$I(t) = \int_{t_1}^t B(\eta) \exp \biggl( -\int_{\eta}^
{t} A(\tau) d\tau \biggr) d\eta $$
I would like to obtain the values of $I(t)$ for all values of $t \in [t_1, t_2]$ with the same timestep $\Delta t$.
I am hoping for a numerical solution with computational complexity better than $O(n^3)$
What have I tried
A naive solution for this problem is $O(n^3)$:
Let outer = array()
for t in [t1, t2]
  Let inner = array()
  for eta in [t1, t]
    inner[eta] = Integrate(A, eta, t)
  outer[t] = Integrate(B * exp(-1 * inner))

So I need to do $n^2$ inner integrals, and $n$ outer integrals, where each integral is $O(n)$.
Why I suspect it can be done faster
If we define $Z(a, b) = \exp \biggl ( - \int_a^b A(\tau) d\tau \biggr )$, the initial integral can be rewritten as
$$I(t) = Z(t_1, t) \int_{t_1}^t \frac{B(\eta)}{Z(t_1, \eta)} d\eta $$
This problem is now $O(n^2)$, because $Z$ has only one variable argument, thus we can spend $O(n^2)$ to compute $Z$ for every value of that argument. Independently, we can spend $O(n^2)$ to integrate $\frac{B}{Z}$ for every value of $t$.
The problem with this formulation is that $\frac{1}{Z}$ is a positive exponent, and gets too big for floating-point numbers (think on the order of $\exp(4000)$).
I further predict that a fast solution solution might involve FFT. The above integrals are a solution to the integrator ODE with variable time constant, and the impact of past values of $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ on future values of $I(t)$ gets exponentially smaller, the further away they are in time. Thus, for a numerical solution, for most combinations of $t$ and $\eta$, the contribution to the final integral will be negligibly small. This seems to me very much in the spirit of FFT, but I do not have sufficient experience in FFT to understand how this problem might translate to a problem solvable by FFT.
